# Excel VBA does not execute code for Pivot table and Pie Chart

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code in which when I click on the button I am able to format the excel data, filter it, delete unnecessary data and then create Pivot table and Chart on a new sheet and rename the sheet as Summary. The problems I am having are:

1.) This work well on all the files I run it on, except one particular file, it run without error, but it doe not create the Pivot Table and it does not create the Chart.

2.) The pie chart codes are recorded, from excel 2013 and it will not run well in excel 2010,(see Sub Pichrt) below, so I a have to create another recorded macros in excel 2010 for my co-workers who are still using excel 2010, is there a way to make 1 code run for both 2010 and 2013, this happen only in the part where it need to create the pie chart. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Sorry for too long code, most are recorded as I am not an expert.
 Thank you.

```
Sub OpenIt()
myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "Browse forWorkbook")
Workbooks.Open myFile
Call KeepOnlyAtSymbolRows
End Sub

Sub KeepOnlyAtSymbolRows()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim lastRow As Long

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Abstraction Data Extract")

lastRow = ws.Range("J" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set rng = ws.Range("J1:J" & lastRow)

   ' filter and delete all but header row
With rng
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>*Yes*"
    .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
End With

   ' turn off the filters
ws.AutoFilterMode = False
lastRow = ws.Range("I" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set rng = ws.Range("I1:I" & lastRow)

   ' filter and delete all but header row
With rng
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>*C=Complete*"
    .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
End With

   ' turn off the filters
ws.AutoFilterMode = False
Call Format
End Sub
Sub Format()
Dim Found As Range
Dim LastRowColumnA As Long
Dim PSheet As Worksheet
Dim DSheet As Worksheet
Dim PCache As PivotCache
Dim PTable As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long


Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter

Set Found = Rows(1).Find(what:="Comments", LookIn:=xlValues, 
lookat:=xlWhole)
If Not Found Is Nothing Then Found.Value = "Differences"

Columns("N:O").Select
Selection.Style = "Currency"
Columns("N:N").Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("N1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Columns("O:O").Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("O1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

Columns("F:F").Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("F1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"

Columns("L:L").Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("L1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"

Columns("G:G").Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("G1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"

LastRowColumnA = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Range("S2:S" & LastRowColumnA).Formula = "=RC[-5]-RC[-4]"

On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("PivotTable").Delete
Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "PivotTable"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True


Set PSheet = Worksheets("PivotTable")
Set DSheet = Worksheets("Abstraction Data Extract")

'Define Data Range
lastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(lastRow, LastCol)

    'Define Pivot Cache
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange). _
CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 2), _
TableName:="OnePivotTable")

   'Insert Blank Pivot Table
Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="OnePivotTable")

  'Insert Row Fields
On Error Resume Next
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("OnePivotTable").PivotFields("DRG Mismatch 
Reason")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 1
'.Caption = "Mismatch Reason"
.PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("OnePivotTable").CompactLayoutRowHeader = "Mistmatch 
Reason"
On Error GoTo 0
End With


  'Insert Data Field
On Error Resume Next
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("OnePivotTable").PivotFields("Final DRG 
Reimbursement")
.Orientation = xlDataField
.Position = 1
.Calculation = xlPercentOfTotal
.NumberFormat = "0.00%"
.Name = "Percent of Total"
End With

On Error Resume Next
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("OnePivotTable").PivotFields("Final DRG 
Reimbursement")
.Orientation = xlDataField
.Position = 2
.Function = xlCount
.NumberFormat = "#,##0"
.Name = "Count"
End With

   'Insert Data Field
On Error Resume Next
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("OnePivotTable").PivotFields("Final DRG 
Reimbursement")
.Orientation = xlDataField
.Position = 3
.Function = xlSum
.NumberFormat = "$#,##0"
.Name = "Final DRG Reimbursement "
End With

   'Insert Data Field
On Error Resume Next
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("OnePivotTable").PivotFields("Working DRG 
Reimbursement")
.Orientation = xlDataField
.Position = 4
.Function = xlSum
.NumberFormat = "$#,##0"
.Name = "Working DRG Reimbursement "
End With

   'Insert Data Field
On Error Resume Next
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("OnePivotTable").PivotFields("Differences")
.Orientation = xlDataField
.Position = 5
.Function = xlSum
.NumberFormat = "$#,##0"
.Name = "Differences "
End With

   'Format Pivot
TableActiveSheet.PivotTables("SalesPivotTable").ShowTableStyleRowStripes = 
True
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SalesPivotTable").TableStyle2 = "PivotStyleMedium9"

Sheets("PivotTable").Name = "Summary"
Call PiChrt
End Sub
Sub PiChrt()

Range("B4:C10").Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(251, xlPie).Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Summary!$B$2:$G$11")
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").IncrementLeft -143.25
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").IncrementTop 50.25
ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementDataLabelBestFit)
ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementDataLabelInsideEnd)
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Select
With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font
    .BaselineOffset = 0
    .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
    .Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorBackground1
    .Fill.ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
    .Fill.ForeColor.Brightness = 0
    .Fill.Transparency = 0
    .Fill.Solid
End With
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").ScaleHeight 1.7239585156, msoFalse, _
    msoScaleFromTopLeft
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").ScaleHeight 1.1208461201, msoFalse, _
    msoScaleFromTopLeft
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").ScaleWidth 1.0416666667, msoFalse, _
    msoScaleFromTopLeft
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 15
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 14
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 13
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 12
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 11
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 10
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 9
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 8
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 7
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 6
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 5
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 4
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 3
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 2
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't checked your complete code for bugs, but the non-creation of a pivot table might be due to the fact that, I don't know for what reason, the PivotRange has to be encoded as a STRING format, using a R1C1 reference style.

This gives:

```
Dim PRange As string

'Define data range 
lastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

PRange = DSheet.Name & "!" & DSheet.Range(DSheet.Cells(1,1), DSheet.Cells(LastRow, LastCol)).Address(ReferenceStyle:=x1A1)

'Define Pivot Cache
'rest of your code
```

Comment: Thank you Lambik, i did that and still did not create the Pivot table and chart in that particular file, others are fine..

Comment: I tried to run the code in a sample workbook, but without result. Since I do not have the original data, TS is difficult. Is the data, the names of the worksheets and the names of the table used to create the pivot always exactly the same?

Comment: I can send you 2 dummy data, 1 on file where it works and another on file where it did not work, yes the name of the worksheet is always the same. The data is downloaded all over different facilities but headers and colums are always the same. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hello Lambik. Your above Tip has solve my Problem, i had my PRange declared as Range in my Code, so i changed it to String as your code suggested, then i inserted the (PRange = DSheet.Name & "!" & DSheet.Range(DSheet.Cells(1,1), DSheet.Cells(LastRow, LastCol)).Address(ReferenceStyle:=x1A1)) as you suggested and removed (Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(lastRow, LastCol)) from my code, so i will check your suggestion as accepted, but my 2nd question above, how do i re write the Sub Pichrt in the code above to work for both excel 2010 and 2013, only work for 2013 for now.

Comment: John, thanks for accepting the answer. It is always good practice to use OPTION EXPLICIT before the code, which forces you to declare all variables, which would probably have returned an error is in this case, alerting your there was something wrong. As I haven't worked in excel 2010 for years, nor do I have any knowledge on the difference between 2010/2013 or a pc with Excel2010, I'm afraid I can't help you on that one. I'm sorry.

Comment: Thank you. For the second part of my question, i figured it out by combining series of code examples from Internet with trial and error i came up with the below code which works both on excel 2010 and 2013 for creating Pie Chart.